# Unable to Install Nuget Packages for ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I had successfully used visual studio for Asp.Net framework 4.7 projects and installed necessary Nuget packages. But I am currently working on an AspNet Core project, I tried adding a view to DotNet Core MVC folder. However, the NuGet package manager could not install the necessary packages. The error message received can be seen in the picture attached.

After trying multiple times to no avail, I searched directly for AspNetCore.MVC.ViewFeatures and AspNetCore.MVC.Razor.ViewCompilation packages and tried to download them via Nuget, but it gave me error messages.

Kindly note that I had searched the internet to resolve this issue and could not find solution. Kindly advise me on what to do. Thank you. [image]

[image]

Comment: please show your csproj file

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the csproj file

Comment: don’t post screenshots. Post code

Comment: try clean your nuget from vs settings.

Comment: Could you please have a try to use Nuget 4.9.1 as screenshot then run your build again?

Comment: Please refer to [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), to create an Asp.net core 3.1 MVC application, we have to use Visual Studio 2019 16.4 or later and [.NET Core 3.1 SDK or later](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1). So, please check the VS version and .Net core version in your machine and try to upgrade them. Besides, we could install the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` to generate the code, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlP3b.png).